# Issue adding zindex div to page

Tags: html, layout

I am having issues adding a div to my page layout, I think I need `z-index` but am unable to get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/xmaudv9c/

when I add:

```
<div id="blue-container">
<img id="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/315x630/293fe6/fff"/>
<div id="blue-text">
    <p>Blue text example<br>
      Blue text example<br>
      Blue text example </p>
  </p>
```

The page is not displaying as I expect. I am trying to get blue-container with blue-text to display on top of it to display to the right of body-main. I think it needs to be in layers - `z-index`?

Thank you.

EDIT: I have added an example image of how I would like it to look - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx6uS.jpg

Comment: what do you want to happen? you have screen shots?

Comment: Hi winresh24, The page is not displaying as I expect. I am trying to get blue-container with blue-text to display on top of it to display to the right of body-main. I think it needs to be in layers - z-index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try My code..I think this is what you looking for.

```
<style>
* {
    margin : 0px;
    padding : 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1440px;
    top : 150pt;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    content: url(http://placehold.it/960x120);
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#buttons {
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top : 15px;
    padding-bottom : 12px;
}
#body-left {
    float: left;
    content: url(http://placehold.it/240x930);
}
#body-right {
    float: left;
    content: url(http://placehold.it/240x930);
}
#body {
    float: left;
    width: 960px;
}
#body-main {
    width: 960px;
    height: 630px;
    background-color: white;
    float:left;
}
span#hometop {
    content: url(http://placehold.it/960x300);
    left : 180.00pt;
    top : 123.75pt;
    width : 720.00pt;
    height : 225.00pt;
}
#blue-container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 315px;
    background:url("http://dummyimage.com/315x630/293fe6/fff");
    float:right;
}
#blue-bg {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#blue-text {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 215px;
    color:#fff;
}
div#body-logo {
    padding-top: 85px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    content: url(http://placehold.it/450x122);
}
div#body-textfull {
    padding-left: 25px;
    left : 198.75pt;
    top : 545.25pt;
    width : 216.75pt;
    height : 256.50pt;
}
#footer {
    content: url(http://placehold.it/960x250);
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}
.text-container{width:450px;
    float:left;}
</style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="buttons">Buttons go here</div>
  <div id="body-left"></div>
  <div id="body"> <span id="hometop"></span>
    <div id="body-main"> 

       <div  class ="text-container">
           <div id="body-logo"></div>     
           <div id="body-textfull">
            <p>body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text body text</p>
          </div>
      </div>           
    <div id="blue-container">
        <div id="blue-text">
            <p>Blue text example<br>
              Blue text example<br>
              Blue text example </p>

            </div>

     </div>
    <!-- End body-main --> 
  </div>
  <!-- End body -->

</div>
 <div id="body-right"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Out this, this suits your Requirement

```
   <html>
<head>

<style> p {
position:relative;
left:0;
}
#blue-container img{
position:absolute;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="blue-container">
<img  id="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/315x630/293fe6/fff"/>
<div id="blue-text">
    <p>Blue text example<br>
      Blue text example<br>
      Blue text example </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but this seems to be the same problem I am having (pushing body-right down) Can you please update jsfiddle.net/xmaudv9c/ with how I would apply to the current style sheet?

Comment: Can You please explain me what exactly you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

you dont need z-index at all in this particular case

### http://jsfiddle.net/xmaudv9c/2/

```
<div id="blue-container">
    <div id="blue-text">
        <p>Blue text example<br>
          Blue text example<br>
          Blue text example </p>
      </p>
</div>
```

i have removed below tag

```
<img id="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/315x630/293fe6/fff"/>
```

CSS - i have removed all the z-index

```
#blue-container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 315px;
    background:url("http://dummyimage.com/315x630/293fe6/fff");
}


#blue-text {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 215px;
    color:#fff;//added color here
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not displaying correctly -- here is a screenshot of what happened when I copy and paste your code (pushing the right-body div down and is display to the left of body-main) - http://imgur.com/yGjyhRY

Comment: I have updated with a screenshot of how I would like it to display - http://imgur.com/3Ap44t1

Comment: No sorry - here is a screenshot of how your code is displaying - http://imgur.com/hT4LDqO